# Recursive Stern-Brocot tree definition

Tags: tikz-trees, recursion

I am trying to build a Stern-Brocot tree (enumeration of rationals).

The result is nearly acceptable, but I am still dissatisfied with the following points.

1. The edge from the parents goes to the middle of the child node, not the upper border.
2. The command does not (re)evaluate it's arguments at each iteration (we keep `1+1+1` instead of `3`)
3. I cannot use `\bt@n` and `\bt@d` in the recursive calls, as they are somehow messed up (why ?).
4. I have to give a name to my nodes, which is useless, but LaTeX won't compile without.

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\eval}[1]{\pgfmathparse{int(#1)}\pgfmathresult}

\makeatletter  % We can use the `@` symbol in macro names
\def\mybtree#1#2#3#4#5{%

  \pgfextra{ % Allows us to use non-drawing commands
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\bt@depth{#5}    % Current depth
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\bt@ndepth{\bt@depth - 1}  % Next depth

    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\bt@n{#1+#3}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\bt@d{#2+#4}

    %% Calculate the sibling distance
    %  distance = 2^{remaining depth}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bt@sdistance{pow( 2, \bt@depth)}
  }

  node (\bt@n/\bt@d) {$\frac{\eval{#1+#3}}{ \eval{#2+#4}}$}

  \ifnumgreater{\bt@depth}{0}{% if( depth > 0 ) then:
    child [sibling distance=\bt@sdistance*2em] {
      \mybtree{#1}{#2}{#1+#3}{#2+#4}{\bt@ndepth}
    } 
    child [sibling distance=\bt@sdistance*2em] { 
      \mybtree{#1+#3}{#2+#4}{#3}{#4}{\bt@ndepth} 
    } 
  }{% else:
    %% Do nothing
  }
}
\newcommand*{\btree}[1]{\mybtree{0}{1}{1}{0}{#1}}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
%% Now we can draw our tree
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \draw \btree{3};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It should give something like this 
[image: Stern-Brocot tree]

So any help is welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can I offer you a [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest)?

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  Stern Brocot/.style n args={5}{%
    content=$\frac{\number\numexpr#1+#3\relax}{\number\numexpr#2+#4\relax}$,
    if={#5>0}{% true
      append={[,Stern Brocot={#1}{#2}{#1+#3}{#2+#4}{#5-1}]},
      append={[,Stern Brocot={#1+#3}{#2+#4}{#3}{#4}{#5-1}]}
    }{}}% false (empty)
[,Stern Brocot={0}{1}{1}{0}{3}]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

### Code (with more stuff)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{strrepeat}{2}{%
  \begingroup\pgfmathint{#2}\pgfmath@count\pgfmathresult
    \let\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
    \pgfutil@loop\ifnum\pgfmath@count>0\relax
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfmathresult\expandafter{\pgfmathresult#1}%
      \advance\pgfmath@count-1\relax
    \pgfutil@repeat\pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  Stern Brocot at/.style={at/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={([rotate around=180:(!##1)] !##22)}
    {strrepeat("#1",\SBLevel)}{strrepeat("#1",\SBLevel-1)}},
  Stern Brocot at*/.style n args={3}{
    at/.wrap pgfmath arg={(!##1-|SB@#3)}{strrepeat("#1",#2)},
    /forest/if={#2<\SBLevel}{append after command=
      (\tikzlastnode) edge[densely dotted] (SB@#3@\the\numexpr\SBLLoop+1\relax)}{}}}
\forestset{
  Stern Brocot*/.style n args={2}{
    content=$\frac{#1}{#2}$,
    edge=densely dotted,
    if={level()<\SBLevel}{append={[,Stern Brocot*={#1}{#2}]}}{}},
  Stern Brocot/.style n args={5}{
    /utils/exec=\edef\SBLevel{#5},@Stern Brocot={#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}},
  @Stern Brocot/.style n args={4}{
    /utils/exec=\edef\SBTop   {\number\numexpr#1+#3\relax}% eTeX instead of PGFmath
                \edef\SBBottom{\number\numexpr#2+#4\relax},
    content/.expanded=$\frac{\SBTop}{\SBBottom}$,
    if/.expanded={level()<\SBLevel}{% true
      append={[,@Stern Brocot={#1}{#2}{\SBTop}{\SBBottom}]},
      append={[,Stern Brocot*={\SBTop}{\SBBottom}]},
      append={[,@Stern Brocot={\SBTop}{\SBBottom}{#3}{#4}]}
    }{}}}% false (empty)
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}[,Stern Brocot={0}{1}{1}{0}{3}]
\coordinate[Stern Brocot at=1] (SB@left) coordinate[Stern Brocot at=3] (SB@right);
\foreach \SBLLoop in {\SBLevel, ..., 0}
  \path node[Stern Brocot at*={1}{\SBLLoop}{left}]  (SB@left@\SBLLoop)  {$\frac01$}
        node[Stern Brocot at*={3}{\SBLLoop}{right}] (SB@right@\SBLLoop) {$\frac10$};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output (with more stuff)

[image]

Comment: Very compact, with new syntax to learn. Thanks !

Comment: Is it also possible to draw the "parents" like in this image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SternBrocotTree.svg ?

Comment: @moose See my update. It includes a new PGFmath function `strrepeat` (`strcat` is from `forest`) that is used to place the `0/1` and `1/0` fractions in dependence of the maximum level. Those  nodes will be placed wrongly if the tree doesn’t grow upwards or downwards.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You may be surprised by the fact that using `\edef\fracTop{...}` or `\def\fracTop{...}` is exactly the same, because `\numexpr` is unexpandable. You probably want `\edef\fracTop{\number\numexpr#1+#3\relax\space}` or you'll be calling `\numexpr` very deeply nested (one level added for each recursion step, so in the example they are three). The final `\space` is for terminating the `<number>` when used later (spaces after numbers are ignored inside `\numexpr`, because they follow a constant).

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your comment. I had `\edef\FracTop{\number…}` in earlier version of my codes and changed the implementation for some reason which I cannot remember anymore. I have now changed both implementations in my answer. The `\space` doesn’t seem to matter, though?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel `\space`, in this particular case, could be omitted. But be careful with the places you intend to use a `<number>`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thank you very much! This is amazing!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Metapost version - mainly to show that recursion works properly in `luamplib`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
path S; S = superellipse(9 right, 12 up, 9 left, 12 down,0.79);
def connect(expr a,b) = 
    draw a -- b cutbefore S shifted a cutafter S shifted b
enddef;              
def putfrac(expr num, den, pos) = 
    draw (left--right) scaled 4 shifted pos;
    label.top(decimal num,pos);
    label.bot(decimal den,pos);
enddef;    
vardef mediant(expr a,b,c,d, depth, L, R) =
    save m,n, p; pair p;
    p = ((L+R)/2,depth * v);
    m = a+c; n = b+d;
    if depth > 1:
        connect(p, mediant(a,b,m,n,depth-1, L, xpart p)) withcolor .53 red;
        connect(p, mediant(m,n,c,d,depth-1, xpart p, R)) withcolor .53 blue;
        connect(p, p shifted (0,-v)) dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
        connect((L, ypart p), (L,ypart p-v)) dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
        if d=0:
            connect((R, ypart p), (R,ypart p-v)) dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
        fi
    fi
    if depth > 0:
        putfrac(m,n,p);
        putfrac(a,b,(L,ypart p));
        if d=0: 
            putfrac(c,d,(R,ypart p));
        fi
    fi
    p
enddef;
beginfig(1);
v = 1.618cm;
z0 = mediant(0,1,1,0, 5, 0,220mm);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the fun of it, here `TeX` used to compute the predecessors of any given rational. Notice that this is *not* an answer to the question.

I am updating the version from September 2013 for the following reasons:

1. one needs to load explicitely `xinttools` now,
2. the method went through computation of coefficients of continued fraction, decrease by one of the last one, re-construction of fraction, and iteration, hence very inefficient,
3. looking at the result I realized there was a bug in the implementation, the decreased by one last coefficient was not correctly braced, hence the whole thing was buggy if some continued fraction coefficient was at least `10` :-(((

The new implementation proceeds not with the coefficients of the continued fraction, but with the convergents. It computes them once and for all. They are among the ancestors of the given fraction, but we need to add more fractions to find all ancestors. The recipe is explained in the code comments. Convergents correspond to locations where one changes direction in moving up the tree.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintcfrac, xinttools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\defSBAncestors [1]{% 
% we first compute all convergents of a positive fraction
% we need to reverse the order, then we will scan and 
% add the needed intermediate fractions.
% \SBA@i will see p/q.p'/q'....... n/1.\relax 
% The ending n/1 is 0/1 if original fraction was <1.
% We need to add intermediate (p-p')/(q-q'), (p-2p')/(q-2q'), ...
   \def\SBAncestors{}%
   \expandafter\SBA@i 
   \romannumeral0\xintlistwithsep.{\xintRevWithBraces{\xintFtoCv{#1}}}.\relax
}
\def\SBA@i #1/#2.{\if1\xintiiIsOne{#1}\xintdothis\SBA@D\fi
                  \if1\xintiiIsOne{#2}\xintdothis\SBA@N\fi
                  \xintorthat\SBA@ii #1/#2.}
\def\SBA@ii #1/#2.#3/#4.{%
    \edef\SBAncestors{\SBAncestors{#1/#2}}%
    \edef\SBA@P {\xintiiSub{#1}{#3}}%
    \edef\SBA@Q {\xintiiSub{#2}{#4}}%
    \if1\xintiiGtorEq {#3}{\SBA@P}\xintdothis\SBA@i\fi
    \xintorthat{\SBA@ii \SBA@P/\SBA@Q.}#3/#4.}

% Treat the special situations N/1 or 1/D

\def\SBA@D 1/#1.#2\relax {\edef\SBAncestors{\SBAncestors
                          \xintApply{1/\@firstofone}{\xintSeq[-1]{#1}{1}}}}

\def\SBA@N #1/#2\relax {\edef\SBAncestors{\SBAncestors\xintSeq[-1]{#1}{1}}}
\makeatother      


\newcommand*\STRUT{\rule[4pt]{0pt}{9pt}} % line spacing

% #1 must evaluate to a **positive** fraction. It will be reduced to smalles
% terms initially.
\newcommand*\ShowParents [1]{%
   \defSBAncestors {#1}%
   $\xintListWithSep{\to}{\xintApply{\STRUT\xintFrac}\SBAncestors}$%
}

\begin{document}

\ShowParents {5}

\ShowParents {1/5}

\ShowParents {23/16}

\ShowParents {355/113}

\ShowParents {137197119/2110810820}

\end{document}
```

[image]