# Creating dots/lines brackets in tree with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am asking myself if I can create dots like the ones in the picture with tikz:

[image: tree example]

Code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=60mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=33mm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=10mm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[sibling distance=5mm]
\node {n} 
    child {node {$\frac{n}{3}$}
        child {node {$\frac{n}{9}$}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}}
        child {node {$\frac{n}{9}$}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}}}
        child {node {$\frac{n}{3}$}
        child {node {$\frac{n}{9}$}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}}
        child {node {$\frac{n}{9}$}
                        child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}}}
        child {node {$\frac{n}{3}$}
            child{node{$\frac{n}{9}$}
                            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}}
            child{node{$\frac{n}{9}$}
                            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}
            child{node {$\frac{n}{27}$}}}
    };
```

And I want to start the dot lines at last child nodes and between the child nodes.

Comment: Yes, you can. You can dot a line by writing `\draw[dotted] ...`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE!

Comment: If you post the code you are using for the tree, somebody can show you how to do the dotted lines. (I'm not clear which ones you mean right now - the horizontal or vertical ones?)

Comment: I edited the main question with the code I am using and what I especially want.

Comment: This question reminds me of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120605

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution using Tikz. The code was heavily based on [this example of a recursion tree](http://1010ling.blogspot.it/2012/02/drawing-recursion-tree-through-latex.html), but also heavily modified to fit your example image. Not sure if you wanted the `cn/n` to be actual fractions, but that's easily fixable starting from the code below.

### Output

[image: scheme figure]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,calc,arrows.meta,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,bending}

\tikzset{
    edge from parent/.style={draw, thick, blue!70!black},
    no edge from this parent/.style={
        every child/.append style={
        edge from parent/.style={draw=none}}},
    level 3/.style={yshift=5cm},
    level 4/.style={level distance=5mm} 
         }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level/.style={sibling distance=40mm/#1},
    text=blue!70!black,
    >=latex,
    font=\sffamily
    ]

\node (z){cn} 
  child {node (a) {cn/2}
    child {node  (b) {cn/4}
      child {node (b1) {$\vdots$}[no edge from this parent]
       child {node (b11) {c}}
      }
      child {node (b2) {$\vdots$}[no edge from this parent]
       child {node (b12) {c}}
      }
    }
    child {node (g) {cn/4}
      child {node (g1) {$\vdots$}[no edge from this parent]
       child {node (g11) {c}}
      }
      child {node (g2) {$\vdots$}[no edge from this parent]
       child {node (g12) {c}}
      }
    }
  }
    child {node (d) {cn/2}
      child {node  (e) {cn/4}
        child {node (e1) {$\vdots$}[no edge from this parent]
         child {node (e11) {c}}
        }
        child {node (e2) {$\vdots$}[no edge from this parent]
         child {node (e12) {c}}
        }
      }
      child {node (f) {cn/4}
        child {node (f1) {$\vdots$}[no edge from this parent]
         child {node (f11) {c}}
        }
        child {node (f2) {$\vdots$}[no edge from this parent]
         child {node (f12) {c}
         }
         }
  }
};

\node[left=5 of z]  (ln1) {cn}[no edge from this parent]
    child {node (ln2) {cn}[no edge from this parent]
        child {node (ln3) {cn}[no edge from this parent]
            child {node (ln4) {}[no edge from this parent]
                child {node (ln5) {cn}}}}};

\path (b12.north east) -- (g11.north west) node [midway] {$\cdots$};
\path (e12.north east) -- (f11.north west) node [midway] {$\cdots$};

\coordinate (cd1) at ($(f12)+(1,0)$);
\coordinate (nb1) at ($(g12)!.5!(e11)$);

\draw[blue!70!black,thick,<->,] 
    (cd1) -- (cd1|-z.east) node [near start, fill=white] {log(n)};

\draw[blue!70!black,dashed,thick,->]    
    ($(z.west)+(-1em,0)$) -- (ln1);
\draw[blue!70!black,dashed,thick,->]    
    ($(a.west)+(-1em,0)$) -- (ln2.east);
\draw[blue!70!black,dashed,thick,->]    
    ($(b.west)+(-1em,0)$) -- (ln3);
\draw[blue!70!black,dashed,thick,->]    
    ($(b11.west)+(-1em,0)$) -- (ln5);

\draw[blue!70!black,thick,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror},->,-{latex[flex=1pt]}] (b11.south west) -- (f12.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the arrow, have you tried the arrows from `arrows.meta` library? (`arrows` is deprecated either-way.) By the way, your usage of `->` and `-latex` is wrong (for lack of a better word). `>` is a short-cut and short-hand for an arrow tip that shall be used generally. Define `>=latex` (or `>=Latex` with the `arrows.meta` library) and then use only `->`, `<->`, etc.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Interesting. Thanks for the heads-up! I'm looking into it and fixing the code. By the way, `>=latex` and `>=Latex`seem to yield the same result, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention the `flex` and the `bend` options for arrows. Needs the `bending` library. Though, OP has used a much smaller arrow tip in relation to the curvature of the brace.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Those are for rotating the arrow tip, correct? I was also interested in the various arrow tips available for `arrows.meta`, since I haven't found anything in the Tikz manual about this.

Comment: Rotating: Kind of. It provides solutions for paths that are curved where a "straight" arrow tip should be placed. If you can't find the library in the manual you are probably not searching in the newest version (3.0.0).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Ok now I'm understanding it better, but there's one thing I can't seem to do properly. Is there a `every edge/.style={}` kind of command I can apply? I tried this and `every path` in the `\tikzset` but nothing works, or it affects the wrong paths (i.e. the tree branches). And in `\begin{tikzpicture}[...]`, I don't know how to properly set the arrow tips. Plus being 1:30 AM does not help. :D Thanks for your help though!

Comment: (+1) just for the arrow on the curly bracket. (I thought that wouldn't work for some reason.) You might want to use `font=\sffamily` to match the style in the OP's image.

Comment: @cfr Yep, you're right. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Alenanno (Sorry for the late response. Haven't seen your comment before.) You set the arrow tip just as before: `-Latex`, for the bended version you use `-{Latex[bend]}` (or `>={Latex[bend]}`. If you want to apply the option `bend` to all arrows in a scope you can to `arrows={[bend]}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel No worries! And thanks for the explanation! :D

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using `forest`. Note that this takes the 'like this' of the target image ***extremely*** seriously. This means that the actual specification of the main tree is very, very compact:

```
   [c, name=node 1
     [, name=node 2 [, name=node 3 [][]][[][]]][[[][]][[][]]]
   ]
```

Obviously if you want something rather less generic, you can specify the contents of the nodes by hand.

Note also that there is really no reason for me to specify the labels of nodes 4-13 in the way I do. In particular, the specification of nodes numbered 10-13 is really just because I wanted to experiment a bit with node walks.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
 \begin{forest}
   for tree={
     font=\sffamily,
     before typesetting nodes={
       if={level>0}{
         if n children=0{
           append/.wrap pgfmath arg={
             [#1, font=\sffamily, edge=dotted]
           }{content("!r")},
           content={},
         }{
           content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={#2n\textfractionsolidus#1}{int(level()*2)}{content("!r")}
         }
       }{
         delay n=1{
           content/.wrap value={##1n},
           node walk={
             every step/.style={alias=node 4}, F,
             every step/.style={alias=node 10}, N,
             every step/.style={alias=node 11}, N,
             every step/.style={alias=node 9},
             node walk={
               rL,
               node walk={
                 every step/.style={alias=node 12}, P,
                 every step/.style={alias=node 13}, P}
             }
           }
         }
       }
     },
   }
   [c, name=node 1
     [, name=node 2 [, name=node 3 [][]][[][]]][[[][]][[][]]]
   ]
   \begin{scope}[font=\sffamily, >=Triangle]
     \node (node 5) [left=25pt of node 4] {cn};
     \foreach \i/\j in {6/3,7/2,8/1} \node (node \i) at (node 5 |- node \j) {cn};
     \foreach \i/\j in {1/8,2/7,3/6,4/5} \draw [densely dashed, ->] (node \i.west) -- (node \j.east);
     \path [draw, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}] (node 9.south east) -- (node 4.south west);
     \path [draw, <->] (node 9.south east) +(15pt,0) coordinate (c) -- (c |- node 1.north) node [pos=.4, fill=white] {log(n)};
   \end{scope}
   \draw [dotted] (node 10.north east) -- (node 11.north west) (node 13.north east) -- (node 12.north west);
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: node walk tree]