# Define tree recursively with Forest

Tags: forest, recursion

I want to let forest draw trees similar to following one *automatically* in a way, that changing the root of the tree will lead to the correct tree for this root.
[image: Example Tree]

The root is any natural number. The rule is child1=floor((parent-1)/2) and child2=floor(parent/2).

For now I wrote a Fortran-95 programm that produces some Forest code, that makes me able to produce such trees.
[image: WideTree]
I would now like to do in a more elaborated way.

I found this code in another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106895/recursive-stern-brocot-tree-definition) and I think it is going in the right direction:

```
\begin{forest}
 Stern Brocot/.style n args={5}{%
  content=$\frac{\number\numexpr#1+#3\relax}
  {\number\numexpr#2+#4\relax}$,
  if={#5>0}{% true
    append={[,Stern Brocot={#1}{#2}{#1+#3}{#2+#4}{#5-1}]},
    append={[,Stern Brocot={#1+#3}{#2+#4}{#3}{#4}{#5-1}]}
       }{}}% false (empty)
   [,Stern Brocot={0}{1}{1}{0}{3}]
\end{forest}
```

But I am not able to understand how these `#1,#2,...` are working.

Comment: Welcome! What do you have so far? Right now, this is just another do-it-for-me without any ducks.

Comment: I read the first answer of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106895/recursive-stern-brocot-tree-definition. I also read the tutorial from the forest documentation. But I have problems understanding how these features of Forest are working.

What i have right now is a small program that writes the tree in Forestsyntax into a file.

Comment: I actually just want to find out how I can do something like this, without browsing and reading around for more hours,
An example of something similar with an explanation would also be sufficient. But I didn't find any.

Comment: Please always post complete code people can compile and include links in your question. Comments are liable to deletion on a regular basis.

Comment: The hashes are just the place holders for the arguments, as in regular macro definitions. The style shown takes 5 arguments, so the place holders are `#1`, `#2`, `#3`, `#4` and `#5`. In the example, these gets the values `0`, `1`, `1`, `0` and `3` respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Note that I think I ought not answer do-it-for-mes, but sometimes do so anyway. When I do so, I do so for me. If the result happens to be of use, so be it. If not, not. Having started from scratch, I am typically less sympathetic to requests for fine-tuning, adjustments, explanations and other follow-up. Fine-tuning and adjustments are typically left as an exercise for the under-exercised reader. Explanations are for specific questions about particular problems, obstacles or code, where a user asks a question which lets me explain this bit, this change or this step. Since do-it-for-mes don't post code, there is no starting point from which to begin an explanation. In any case, I answer these solely for me. Any explanation is for me.*

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  parhau/.style={
    delay={
      tempcounta/.process={O+nw+P {content}{int(floor((##1-1)/2))}},
      tempcountb/.process={O+nw+P {content}{int(floor(##1/2))}},
      if={
        >Rn>{tempcounta}{0}
      }{
        prepend/.process={ RSn=?_ lw2  {tempcounta}{1}{}{parhau}{[##2, ##1]} },
      }{},
      append/.process={ RSn=?_ lw2  {tempcountb}{1}{}{parhau}{[##2, ##1]} },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  parhau
  [20]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>parhau</code> recursion]

Comment: Togheter with the Forest Documentation I was able to learn alot from this. What still confuses me: What is the job of the first '>' in this line: >Rn>{tempcounta}{0}.

Comment: @Imperaton See page 64. It is not using the `.process` handler, but the generic `<forestmath>`. Hence the switch.

Comment: Do you always use ##1,##2,... (and not #1,#2) for the wrap process, or does it have a special reason here?

Comment: @Imperaton No. It is in a style, so one hash would be an argument passed to the style.